# How to properly use flutter riverpod to share data between widgets in different files?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am able to share data between widgets when the widgets are int he same file but when the widgets are in different files, the ui does not rebuild and i do not seem to get it right.

Please kindly check my codes below and see where I'm falling short.
(I added image for easy reading and text code for  easy CTRL C - CTRL V)

## **Objective**

I'm trying to share data between multiple widgets in different files [image: IMAGE HERE]

but it doesn't notify the other widgets / rebuild
When button at **line 45** is tapped, text at **line 44** change successfully
but screen at **line 26** doesn't change

**//--------------navigation_provider.dart----------------//**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
class NavigationProvider extends ChangeNotifier{

bool showUserProfile = true;
  
void toggleProfile(toggle){
showUserProfile = toggle;
notifyListeners();
}
}
```

**//--------------desktop_scaffold.dart----------------//**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:premiumpeaches/providers/navigation_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final navigatorProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => NavigationProvider());
class DesktopScaffold extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: ref.watch(navigatorProvider).showUserProfile == true ? UserProfileComponent() : ProfileSettingsComponent()
    )
  
}
```

**//--------------user_profile_component.dart----------------//**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:premiumpeaches/providers/navigation_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final navigatorProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => NavigationProvider());
class UserProfileComponent extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return InkWell(
onTap:(){
ref.watch(navigatorProvider).toggleProfile(false);
},
child:Text('Click Me')
)
  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined `navigatorProvider` twice.

That's likely the source of your problem. Two providers mean two different states. So interacting with one `navigatorProvider` has no effect on the other

Rather than defining `navigatorProvider` twice, you most likely instead want to import it.

For example inside `desktop_scaffold.dart` you could do:

```dart
import 'user_profile_component.dart';
```

You can then use `navigatorProvider` all the same. But now, you only have a single `navigatorProvider`, so all interactions goes through that one.

Comment: I defined ```NavigatorProvider``` separately in in different files. How do I use one for all

Comment: after i did
```import 'user_profile_component.dart';``` in **desktop_scaffold**, I passed the ChangeNotifierProvider to user_profile_component using ```UserProfileComponent(navigatorProvider)```

but when i tried to do a watch in user_profile_component using ```ref.watch(this.widget.navigatorProvider)!.showUserProfile.toString()```, 

i got an error message that **"The getter 'showUserProfile' isn't defined for the type 'ChangeNotifier'."**

Comment: You didn't do what I told you. I said to just remove the second provider and add an import. Do nothing else.

Comment: So I had to also import **desktop_scaffold.dart** in  **user_profile_component.dart** to be able to access it's ChangeNotifierProvider   and i was able to use ```ref.watch(navigatorProvider).showUserProfile.toString()``` in user_profile_component and it worked

Thanks to @saytoonz https://stackoverflow.com/users/10117989/saytoonz for some insight

Comment: So I've revised my code by defining ```
final navigatorProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => NavigationProvider()``` in my constants.dart  and imported **constant.dart** anywhere needed.... Thanks. Your answer gave me much insight and comprehension. I appreciate a lot.